# Passing list object into configMap data section

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I want to pass a list object in the data section of configMap in application YAML file.

I have the following list in the properties file:

```
abc.management.provider[0].url=https://example.com
 abc.management.provider[0].username=John
 abc.management.provider[1].url=https://example2.com
 abc.management.provider[1].username=Targerian
```

YAML file:

```
data:
    abc_management:
      provider:
        - url: "https://example.com"
          username: "John"
        - url: "https://example2.com"
          username: "Targerian"
```

I'm getting this error: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap: Data: ReadString: expects " or n,.

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

> what should I do?

This mostly depends on how your application reads the configuration.

If it works for you, you an [create the `ConfigMap` directly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) with your properties-file:

```
kubectl create configmap app-config --from-file=app.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question points to what the nature of a ConfigMap object is. Under the hood, it seems `ConfigMap`s do not explicitly handle lists, so in the end it just depends on how you read that content.

> The data field is designed to contain UTF-8 byte sequences ...
>
> Each key under the data or the binaryData field must consist of
> alphanumeric characters, -, _ or .. The keys stored in data must not
> overlap with the keys in the binaryData field.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmap-object